# Why isn't the "Revisions to post" page mobile-friendly?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, revision-history

I opened [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44879860/revisions) on my mobile through Google Chrome and it took me a couple of seconds before I realized everything was smaller and I had to zoom in, or rather, this was the only page that I had ever encountered that didn't have a mobile version.

There was only Chrome's tab at the bottom of the window offering me a mobile-friendly version of the same page, which I tried and which wasn't really good.

Comment: I have an iPod Touch that I occasionally use (it uses the Safari browser) and there are many bugs, mostly CSS-related. I think the techs are probably inondated with bug reports and probably can't fix them (all). One bug I reported, I needed to be specific about in order for them to track down the offending (css) rule. The (new) ones I have would just be too numerous so I learned to just live with it/them.

Comment: I cannot relate to the bugs that you're talking about but I hope it's clear that mine is a feature-request and not a bug to be solved by a one-liner CSS.

Comment: The same is the case with many other pages with Review posts being one of them.